If $u>0$ is $C^0(\Omega)\cap H^1(\Omega)$ and vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$, then up to a zero extension, is the new function also $H^1$?
I'm trying to show that if $u$ is positive, continuous and $\Delta u\geq 0$ in $\Omega$, and if $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, then let $\tilde u$ be the zero extension of $u$, I want to say that $\tilde u$ is also subharmonic. This conclusion holds when $\tilde u$ is $H^1(\mathbb R^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb R^n)$, however, since I do not have any regularity of $\partial \Omega$, I'm not sure if $\tilde u\in H^1$.

This follows from the "ACL" characterization of Sobolev spaces:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbf R^n$ be an open set and let $1 \le p < \infty$. A function $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ belongs to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if and only if $f$ is (or more precisely, has a representative that is) absolutely continuous on almost every line segment in $\Omega$ that is parallel to the coordinate axes, and the classical partial derivatives of $f$ belong to $L^p(\Omega)$.

The details might get involved, but your extension $\bar u$ will satisfy ACL and thus belong to $W^{1,2}(\mathbf R^n)$.

The answer is yes. The hint is trying to show the following: denote the weak gradient as $\nabla$, $\nabla u\in L^2(\Omega)$, and

$\nabla \tilde{u}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, this can be done by showing $\nabla \tilde{u} = \nabla u$ in $\Omega$ and zero elsewhere.

Note that the regularity of $\partial \Omega$ inherits from the requirement of applying the divergence theorem (or integration by parts) to get the weak derivative, i.e., $\partial \Omega$ should be piecewise "smooth", and this is normally given by default. If you are working on domains with "rough" boundaries, there are numerous treatises dedicated to this (e.g., people who study hyperbolic conservation laws for gases have to use the divergence theorem in rough geometries). Gauging the level of difficulties this problem tries to test the reader, I do not believe that will be the case.
BTW: it should be $C^0(\overline{\Omega})\cap H^1(\Omega)$.

Yes, actually the origin problem is that $\Delta u=0$ in $\Omega$, thus the Sard Theorem can help me to obtain that $D\tilde u$ exists. As for general case, I might need the regularity of $\partial \Omega$, probably if $ \Omega$ is set of finite perimeter, then the statement holds?

@Bountyhunter the general setting is that $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain, and you can safely do whatever manipulation you want on that. Verifying zero extension of a homogeneous BVP's solution being in the same-exponent Sobolev space (but in the whole space) is a typical problem that tests one's understanding of weak derivative. Just applying the definition of the weak derivative on $\nabla \tilde{u}$ you will see what I mean (I normally assign this problem to my students as well).

Thanks a lot, I think what you say can be precisely stated as: For classical case, If $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz, $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $h\in H^1(\mathbb R^n\setminus \Omega)$, then the function $F$ defined as $F=u\in \Omega$ and $F=h\in R^n\setminus \Omega$ is $H^1$ iff trace$(u)$=trace$(h)$. And such statement also holds if $\Omega$ is finite perimeter, since we can consider $\mathcal F\Omega$ instead of $\partial \Omega$. I think for a general domain, at least we need $\tilde u\in BV(\mathbb R^n)$ and I want to show $|D\tilde u|(\partial \Omega)=0$.

@Bountyhunter BV functions can be discontinuous, which should not be a correct space to consider this BVP. Your extension has to be continuous, the continuity (in strong sense or integrating against arbitrary smooth test function over arbitrary hypersurface is continuous) is the key to showing that the weak derivative of the extension exists and coincides with that of the original function in $\Omega$.
